# TestNG expectedException not finding thrown Exception

Tags: java, spring, testng

I have a class that is used to map values passed in via REST from a json object.  The front end javascript is making all the values strings that are passed in.  Using Spring and Jackson if I just needed string values, everything works fine.  However, I have a field that I need to convert to an int.  Since it could be possible to submit an unparseable string, I've got it in a try/catch block that should throw a FormatNumberException.  I have a test method that is supposed to be testing to make sure this error is thrown.  However, it's not catching it, and it is throwing this exception as it should, but the test is still failing.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code for the method in MyClass:
    public void setMaxNumOfFiles(String value) // throws NumberFormatException
    {

```
    try
    {
        this.maxNumOfFiles = Integer.parseInt(value);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I've got the throws part commented out for the last try I did.
This is the code for my test:
    public void setMaxNumOfFiles(String value) // throws NumberFormatException
    {

```
    try
    {
        this.maxNumOfFiles = Integer.parseInt(value);
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Pretty simple I thought.  Below is the console that is given to me when I run my test:

```
{
    java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "foo"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
...
PASSED: setMaxNumOfFilesShouldSetToAndIntegerIfPassedString
FAILED: setMaxNumOfFilesShouldThrowExceptionIfPassedInUnparseableString
org.testng.TestException: 
Method      HeaderQueryTest.setMaxNumOfFilesShouldThrowExceptionIfPassedInUnparseableString()[pri:0, instance:test.visa.casanalytics.model.HeaderQueryTest@47f37ef1] should have thrown an exception of type class java.lang.NumberFormatException
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleInvocationResults(Invoker.java:1405)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:690)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:834)
at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1142)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:124)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:108)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:771)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:357)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:352)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:310)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:259)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1176)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1101)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1009)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.run(RemoteTestNG.java:111)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:204)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:175)


===============================================
    Default test
    Tests run: 35, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================


===============================================
Default suite
Total tests run: 35, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.EmailableReporter2@77afea7d: 22 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.XMLReporter@3d04a311: 25 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.SuiteHTMLReporter@299a06ac: 262 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by [FailedReporter passed=0 failed=0 skipped=0]: 22 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.JUnitReportReporter@5f8ed237: 12 ms
[TestNG] Time taken by org.testng.reporters.jq.Main@2e5c649: 83 ms

}
```

Comment: If you catch your exception straight away, how is TestNG supposed to know about it? TestNG expected exception simply lchecks what exceptions are thrown out of the test method, any exceptions that are caught before that don't count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get rid of the catch and try and let the exception be thrown, add throws to the test method. Add the exception in expectedExceptions. Your test method will pass after receiving the expected exception

Comment: Thanks!  Yeah, I was using an example that had that format, but they were doing something a big different in the test method and were throwing there.